# pH change with pressure in a bicarbonate buffer system

Tags: aqueous-solution

Looking at small scale bioreactors with no added pressure (1atm) compared to a commercial bioreactor which is pressured to 5 psi, where both have the same concentration of sodium bicarbonate, if both reactors are at pH of 7.2, should the pCO2 be the same as well? I've been trying to figure this out using Henry's law as well as the Henderson-Hasselbach equation but feel that the added pressure means that the equilibria for solubility and also acid dissociation should be altered and make the previous question false. Thoughts?